# What is the best way to get the CDDB info for an audio CD in Perl?

Tags: perl, cd-rom

What is the best way to get the cd-title and the cd-track-names from an audio CD?
I tried this module, but it didn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CDDB_get qw( get_cddb );

my %config;
$config{CDDB_HOST} = "freedb.freedb.org";
$config{CDDB_PORT} = 8880;
$config{CDDB_MODE} = "cddb";
$config{CD_DEVICE} = "/dev/sr1";

# user interaction welcome?
$config{input} = 1;

my %cd = get_cddb( \%config ); # line 16

print "$_ : $cd{$_}\n" for keys %cd;

unless( defined $cd{title} ) {
    die "no cddb entry found";
}

print "artist: $cd{artist}\n";
print "title: $cd{title}\n";
print "category: $cd{cat}\n";
print "cddbid: $cd{id}\n";
print "trackno: $cd{tno}\n";

my $n = 1;
for my $i ( @{$cd{track}} ) {
    print "track $n: $i\n";
    $n++;
}

# OUT:
# Odd number of elements in hash assignment at ./cddb_get.pl line 16.
# Use of uninitialized value in list assignment at ./cddb_get.pl line 16.
# Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./cddb_get.pl line 18.
#  :
# no cddb entry found at ./cddb_get.pl line 21.
```

Comment: What, more specifically, didn't work?

Comment: Uups, it works, but not with all cd's.

Comment: @sid_com Of course not. Not all CDs are in FreeDB. :)

Comment: Just to note: that information isn't on a normal audio CD. You collect fingerprint information from the CD and use that to query a database that attempts to match up what you sent it. Ensure that a program such as iTunes can fetch that information before you think your script is broken. :)

Comment: I have read in now more den 200 CD's; for five CD's there were no entry in the database, four of them are a little bit exotic, so I wouldn't have tried with these. Unfortunately I used the only "normal" CD, that didn't work to test the script and I looked too much at the script, so it didn't cross my mind to change the CD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting

```
BEGIN { $CDDB_get::debug = 1 }
```

before the `use CDDB_get` line in order to get debugging output to STDERR.

Comment: cddb: result: 202 No match for disc ID xxxxxxxx.

Comment: So, technically, the module did work after all, and this is a non-question? :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the API URL to FreeDB is correct in the module?

Can you try HTTP instead of CDDBP?

From [the FreeDB documentation](http://www.freedb.org/en/applications__how_to_access.5.html):

> Configure your CDDB1- or freedb-aware
>   software to point to freedb.freedb.org
>   (Random freedb server) as your
>   CDDB/freedb-server.
>
> All official freedb servers are
>   running cddbp at port 8880 and http at
>   port 80. The path for http-access is
>   /~cddb/cddb.cgi.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider looking information up on [musicbrainz.org](http://musicbrainz.org/) instead.

Using MusicBrainz::DiscID to find the discid of a cd and WebService::MusicBrainz to retrieve the data is quite easy:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use MusicBrainz::DiscID;
use WebService::MusicBrainz;

my $discid=MusicBrainz::DiscID->new;
if ( !$discid->read ) {
    print STDERR "Error: " . $discid->error_msg . "\n";
    exit 1;
}
print "DiscID: " . $discid->id . "\n";

my $service=WebService::MusicBrainz->new_release;
my $response=$service->search({ DISCID=>$discid->id });
my $release=$response->release;

print "ARTIST: " . $release->artist->name . "\n";
print "ALBUM:  " . $release->title . "\n";
```